# Single walker MCMC using emcee

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the MCMC implementation emcee in python with only a single walker given 15 parameters? Or do I have to use a different implementation? I want to do this as I only need a single sample from the resulting posterior distribution and computation time is the biggest concern for me at the moment.
Furthermore, I can compute the maximum likelihood estimator quite efficiently, so if I let my one walker start at that point burn in should happen quite quickly if the posterior is nice enough (close to normal distribution), right?
Thanks :)